# ASP.NET Framework - csproj and .sln not appearing in my project

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

There is an old project on .NET Framework 4.0 I'm to work on, and probably upgrade to 4.8.

[image: framework_project]

I found out that it does not have a `.csproj` nor a `.sln` file, so I opened it as a website in Visual Studio 2019.

I tried to right click, and found no property.

How do I restore `.csproj` and `.sln` and also upgrade to .NET Framework 4.8?